# how to mock keystore.getInstance() which returns the keystore object?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have tried to mock the KeyStore.getInstance() which returns the keyStore object
here the below code which I had tired,

**Junit:**

```
KeyStore keyStoreMock = PowerMockito.mock(KeyStore.class); 
PowerMockito.when(KeyStore.getInstance(any())).thenReturn(keyStoreMock); 
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(keyStoreMock).load(any(InputStream.class),Mockito.any(char[].class)); 
X509Certificate cert = Mockito.mock(X509Certificate.class); 
when(keyStoreMock.getCertificate(any())).thenReturn(cert); 
when(cert.getNotAfter()).thenReturn(mockDate);
```

unable to mock keyStore.getInstance() which returns the of KeyStore class mock object.

**Source Code:**

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(new FileInputStream(filename), password.toCharArray());
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)keystore.getCertificate("Cert_name");  
endate = certificate.getNotAfter();
```

I think KeyStore.getInstance() returns null, how to overcome this issue.

Colud any one plz help me out to mock the keystore.getInstance() method.

Comment: can be marked as duplicate, this question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354270/how-to-mock-keystore-class-and-assign-mock-behavior-to-its-methods

Comment: @PraveenKumarMekala actullay i have tried with ref link but i am unable to mock the KeyStore.getInstance() method

Comment: change @PrepareTest to PrepareForTest and PowerMockito.mock(keystore.class) to PowerMockito.mockStatic(keystore.class) also before PrepareForTestadd RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation and try

Comment: @PraveenKumarMekala i am updated as per the above update but also i am not able to mock the keystore.getInstance() method which returns keystore object

Comment: tried using any() instead of anyString()?

Comment: @PraveenKumarMekala thnaks for you update But i am not able to mock the KeyStore.getInstance(). Here the below snnipet i have tried with your updates

Comment: can you update question with same details and also error trace if you're getting any(I'm assuming keystore.getInstance is returning null)

Comment: @PraveenKumarMekala  yes, it is returning null.i think  that the reason i am unable to mock Could you pls help me out.

Comment: try with below solution, if it  not working try with any instead of anyString

Answer (score -2):

```
@Runwith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(KeyStore.class)
public class TestClass {

    @InjectMock
    //Actual Class
    @Mock
    KeyStore mockKeyStore;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        KeyStore keyStoreMock = PowerMockito.mockStatic(KeyStore.class);
        PowerMockito.when(keyStore.getInstance(any())).thenReturn(mockKeyStore);//use this line or
        //use below two lines
        KeyStore powerMockKey = PowerMockito.mock(KeyStore.class);
        Mockito.when(KeyStore.getInstance(anyString())).thenReturn(powerMockKey));        
    }         
}
```

Comment: Tried with both the above Snippet of  code but unable to mock the KeyStore.getInstance.it returning original keyStore Object.

Answer (score -2):

Just executed this with power mock, this seems to work as well.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;

@PrepareForTest(KeyStore.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.security.*"})
public class MyKeyTest {
  @Test
  public void mockKeyStore() throws Exception{
    KeyStore keyStoreMock = mock(KeyStore.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(KeyStore.class, invocation -> keyStoreMock);
    when(KeyStore.getInstance(any())).thenReturn(keyStoreMock);
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(keyStoreMock).load(any(InputStream.class), any(char[].class));
    X509Certificate cert = Mockito.mock(X509Certificate.class);
    when(keyStoreMock.getCertificate(any())).thenReturn(cert);
    when(cert.getNotAfter()).thenReturn(new Date());
    Assert.assertEquals(keyStoreMock,KeyStore.getInstance("x"));
    Assert.assertEquals(keyStoreMock,KeyStore.getInstance("y"));
    Assert.assertEquals(keyStoreMock,KeyStore.getInstance("MarbleCake"));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your update, But it is also not working.It returns the original keyStore object

Comment: did not understand that part , what does original key store mean

Comment: i mean keyStore.getInstance is not returning keyStoreMock

Comment: can you show me how that was determined , just so that i can look at it ?

Comment: Just so that i was sure , i added assertions. They return the mock dont they ?. They pass for me!

Comment: Could you pls check out my updated post with Source code

Comment: When i was debugging it is not returning keyStoreMock for KeyStore.getInstance() , but Finally i want to get the mock endDate of a certificate

Comment: did you find the solution for mocking KeyStore? I'm facing the same problem with KeyFactory.class